# Im getting a 'NoReverseMatch' error during template rendering

Tags: python, django

Currently reading the Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes and I'm trying to code a simple learning lo using python and Django, but I keep getting an error when I try to enter the topics URL. The error seems to come from the base.html(the template), it says that learning_logs is not a registered namespace, even tho I have written it as a variable named app_name and have included it in the URLs.

Here's the code:

main **urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include , re_path

app_name = 'learning_logs'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('' , include(("learning_logs.urls", app_name ) ))
]
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path , re_path
from . import views

app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('topics/', views.topics , name='topics'),
    re_path(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$' , views.topic , name = 'topic'),
    re_path(r'^new_topic/$' , views.new_topic , name = 'new_topic'),
    re_path(r'^new_entry/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$' , views.new_entry , name = 'new_entry'),
]
```

**base.html:**

```
     <p>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">Learning Log</a>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Topics</a>
    </p>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
```

Error:
[image: Pic]

Comment: Check that the app is included in the INSTALLED_APPS settings.

Comment: it is there with the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fix the main `urls.py` file as the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include , re_path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('' , include(("learning_logs.urls", app_name='learning_logs') ))
]
```

Note the named parameter `app_name=` in `include`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix the declarations in the main **urls.py** by removing the `app_name` and fixing the include.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('' , include('learning_logs.urls'))
]
```

Comment: i keep getting the same error , but thank you either way